# How to generate JWT Token using Facebook credentials in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have one requirement that have to develop Spring boot Rest API for login using Facebook credentials and have to generate JWT token for this credentials and validate every request.

Thanks.

Comment: I hope you already know about JWT tokens. Documentation is available for it if not familiar with it. I would suggest you not to include the facebook credentials into the JWT. Instead of doing that, you should generate the a random token that will be stored in some kind of storage like persistence or maybe a cache. Each time, on the authorisation of the every request you can retrieve the facebook credential from the cache or persistence and validate the token. Let me know in comments if you need more help or I missed something.

Comment: Hi Nisheeth, I got your point. But my requirement is use needs to login with Facebook credentials and have to validate the use further request.

Comment: for example. If I have logged in with facebook credential on xyz App. next i'm trying to access some confidential information on this time have to validate the use whether the use is authorised or not. This is what my requirement. Can you please assist me. Thanks.

Comment: When the user logs in using facebook credentials, the user will be authenticated by the facebook and will issue the token that can be used for authorisation. My point is that once you authenticate the user on facebook, you get the credential. Instead of wrapping it into the JWT, store it somewhere with id and wrap that ID in the JWT. On each request, you will receive the JWT token and while authorising, you can get id from the JWT and get it from the persistence or store and authorise the user.

Comment: OK, Can you please share me the code snip/ link for get the user credentials after authentication done by facebook.

Comment: Sure thing. I will be posting an example here shortly.

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in using facebook credentials, the user will be authenticated by the facebook and will issue the token that can be used for authorisation. My point is that once you authenticate the user on facebook, you get the credential. Instead of wrapping it into the JWT, store it somewhere with id and wrap that ID in the JWT. On each request, you will receive the JWT token and while authorising, you can get id from the JWT and get it from the persistence or store and authorise the user.

Let say you have the facebook tokens after login, then you have to store it somewhere using some id
`String fbTokenId = storeFBToken(fbToken);`. Using this token you can generate JWT token like:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(key);
String token = JWT.create().withIssuer(author)
            .withClaim("fbTokenId", fbTokenId)
            .withSubject("user")
            .sign(algorithm);
```

When you authorise the request, you will have the JWT token. Now you have to get verify the token and read the `fbTokenId` to verify it:

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(key);
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(author)
        .build();
DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
String fbTokenId = jwt.getClaim("fbTokenId").as(String.class);
String fbToken = getFBTokenFromStore(fbTokenId);
```

Before you jump into this, make sure you understand stateless authentication and authorisation concepts especially with tokens.

Find a sample authentication application [here](https://github.com/szerhusenBC/jwt-spring-security-demo/tree/master/src/main/java/org/zerhusen/security)

Comment: Can you please share the reference link Where i can find full code

Comment: What spring boot version are you using?

Comment: Have a look at the link I have added in the post.